# Can't find the rb slot in player script component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following a unity practice from youtube and seem to have problems at 6:42.

here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE7gc1sblUA/

and a screenshot:

[image]

and the script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {

      public float jumpforce = 10f; 

      public rigidbody2D rb;

      // Update is called once per frame
      void Update() {
         if (input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;
         }
      }
   }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your script will have compiler errors since `rigidbody2D` should start with an uppercase `R`